# How to get the svg node when we drag the li item into d3 tree chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

When I drag the **li** item into the **D3 tree**, the **li** will be add to tree. But i can't get the node value when i drag the **li** to add to the tree. And also can you suggest that what is the simple way to add li to tree when we drag.Thanks in advance.

Comment: d3.select(this) not working for you in your drag handler?

Comment: when i use this i will get output like **[object Window]**, but i didn't get the d value to append my dragged element data.

Comment: Hmm... okay then, can you upload your code(such as fiddle), so people here can really help you.

Comment: @DavidGuan [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1wg7rLjd/3/) i am new for it can you check it once..